# Changing title only saves for a few seconds (until page stops loading)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tampermonkey, javascript-injection

Im trying to change the title of youtube page (so that the tab at the top of the browser changes to "test" instead of "youtube"). It changes for a few seconds, changing from "youtube" to "test", and then reverts to the default, "Youtube," after the page stops loading. I am using Chrome and the tampermonkey extension to inject my code (also using jquery). How do I make the change stay during the life cycle of the webpage? Here is the code below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hello World App
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      *.youtube.*
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.jQuery;
$(document).prop('title', 'test');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MutationObserver to detect the exact moment when the title is changed by the site:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YT title
// @match    https://www.youtube.com/*
// @run-at   document-start
// ==/UserScript==

if (!checkHead()) {
  new MutationObserver((_, ob) => checkHead() && ob.disconnect())
    .observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true});
}

function checkHead() {
  if (document.head) {
    overrideTitle();
    return true;
  }
}

function overrideTitle(title = 'foo') {
  new MutationObserver(() => {
    if (document.title !== title) {
      document.title = title;
    }
  }).observe(document.head, {childList: true, characterData: true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YouTube almost certainly dynamically changes their title over the lifetime of the page, so it will overwrite any change you make to it. The only way around this would be to change the title back at regular intervals, so setInterval would be what you're looking for.

```
var $ = window.jQuery;
window.setInterval(function() {
    $(document).prop('title', 'test');
}, 1000);
```

The 1000 means every 1000ms, or 1 second, the title will be reset to "test".